# ArrayBlockingQueue synchronization in multi node deployment

Tags: java

In simple description, I have a servlet and response time is long so I decided to divide it into two parts, one just composes a response to client, and second let's say performs some business logic and stores result in DB. To decrease response time I execute business logic asynchronously using `ThreadPoolExecutor` in combination with `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Using `ArrayBlockingQueue` I can ensure original FIFO ordering if requests were sequential for the same client. This is important prerequisite.

Here is a snippet:

Servlet

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet { 
    AsyncExecutor exe = new AsyncExecutor();       
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter w = resp.getWriter();       
        exe.executeAsync(exe.new Task(this));   
        w.print("HELLO TO CLIENT");
    }   
    protected void someBusinessMethod(){
        // long time execution here
    }
}
```

and   Executor

```
public class AsyncExecutor {
    static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10, true);    
    static final Executor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 5, 20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);    
    public void executeAsync(Task t){
        boolean isTaskAccepted = false;
        while(!isTaskAccepted){
            try {                               
                executor.execute(t);
                isTaskAccepted = true;
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException e){             
            }
        }   
    }   
    class Task implements Runnable{
        private HelloServlet servlet;       
        Task(HelloServlet servlet){
            this.servlet = servlet;                 
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // just call back to servlet's business method      
            servlet.someBusinessMethod();           
        }       
    }   
}
```

This implementation works fine if I deploy it only to one Tomcat node, since I have only one ArrayBlockingQueue in application. But if I have several nodes and load balancer in front then I can not guarantee FIFO ordering of requests for async execution for the same client since I have already several Queues. 
My question is, how it is possible to guarantee the same order of requests to be executed asynchronously for the same client in clustered (multi node) deployment? I think ActiveMQ probably a solution (not preferable for me), or load balancer configuration, or can it be implemented in code?

Hope some of these ideas help.

**Thanks Sam for you prompt suggestions**.

In the first post I described a problem in very simplified way so to clarify it better let's say I have a legacy web app deployed to Tomcat and it serves some Licensing Model(old one). Then we got a new Licensing Model (this is a GlassFish app) and we need to use it alongside with old one to be in sync. For the end user such integration must be transparent and not intrusive. So user request is served like this.

1. caller send a request (create subscription for example)
2. execute business logic of the the new licensing model
3. execute business logic of the the old licensing model
4. despite the result of the p.3 return response of p.2 in format of old licensing model back to caller
5. (optional) handle failure of p.3 if any

This was implemented with Aspect which intercepts requests of p.1 and executes the rest of stuff sequentially. And as I said in previous post p.3 execution time can be long that's why I want to make it asynchronous. Let's have a look at snippet of Aspect (instead of Servlet from the first post).

```
@Aspect @Component public class MyAspect {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx; 
@Autowired
private AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor;

@Around("@annotation(executeOpi)")
public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, ExecuteOpi executeOpi) throws Throwable {

    LegacyMapper newModelExecutor = ctx.getBean(executeOpi.legacyMapper());

            // executes a new  model and then return result in the format of old model      
            Object result = newModelExecutor.executeNewModelLogic(joinPoint.getArgs());
    // executes old model logic asynchronously 
    asyncExecutor.executeAsync(asyncExecutor.new Task(this, jp)     


    return object
}


public void executeOldModelLogic(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{
    // long time execution here
    jp.proceed();       
 }
}
```

With this implementation as in the first post, I can guarantee a FIFO order of executeOldModelLogic methods, if requests come to the same Tomcat node. But with multi-node deployment and round robin LB in front I can end-up with such a case when for the same caller "update subscription in old model" can come first to ArrayBlockingQueue than "create subscription in old model", which of course a bad logical bug.

And as for points you suggested:

p1, p2 and p4: I probably can't use it as a solution since I don't have a state of object as such. You see that I pass to Runnable task a references of Aspect and JoinPoint to make a call back of executeOldModelLogic from Runnable to Aspect

p3 Don't know about this might be worthwhile to investigate

p5 This is a direction I want go for further investigation, I have a gut feeling it is only way to solve my problem in the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions that come to mind off hand.

1. Use the database: post the jobs to be run in a database table, have a secondary server process run the jobs, and place results in an output table. Then when users call back to the web page, it can pick up any results waiting for them from the output table.
2. Use a JMS service: this is a pretty lightweight messaging service, which would integrate with your Tomcat application reasonably well. The downside here is that you have to run another server side component, and build the integration layer with your app.  But that's not a big disadvantage.
3. Switch to a full J2EE container (Java App Server): and use an EJB Singleton. I have to admit, I don't have any experience with running a Singleton across separate server instances, but I believe that some of them may be able to handle it.
4. Use EHCache or some other distributed cache: I built a Queue wrapper around EHCache to enable it to be used like a FIFO queue, and it also has RMI (or JMS) replication, so multiple nodes will see the same data.
5. Use the Load Balancer: If your load balancer supports session level balancing, then all requests for a single user session can be directed to the same node.  In a big web environment where I worked we were unable to share user session state across multiple servers, so we set up load balancing to ensure that the user's session always was directed to same web server.

Hope some of these ideas help.